# Group rows based on difference from previous row

Tags: r, loops

I have a data.frame with difftimes created with `hms::hms` on it.
I know I can use `arrange()` and `diff()` to check the time elapsed between each observation.

How can I create a `$session` variable that changes its value when the time elapsed is bigger than a predefined value?

For example, given the data below:

```
    hour         time_elapsed
15:58:05                   NA
15:58:11                    6
15:58:17                    6
15:58:44                   27
15:58:51                    7
15:58:57                    6
```

Considering values bigger than 25 as the breaking point, we would have:

```
    hour         time_elapsed     session
15:58:05                   NA           1
15:58:11                    6           1
15:58:17                    6           1
15:58:44                   27           2
15:58:51                    7           2
15:58:57                    6           2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `with(df1, cumsum(replace(time_elapsed, is.na(time_elapsed), 0) >25) + 1)`

Comment: Perfect! A very simple solution indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `replace` the `NA` with 0, then create a logical condition and do the cumulative sum

```
df1$session <- with(df1, cumsum(replace(time_elapsed, is.na(time_elapsed), 0) >25) + 1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I might need to do some homework to understand the usage of `with` and how it changes the behavior of `cumsum` on this.

Comment: @BrunoRitter  Using `with`, you don't have to extract the column.  Otherwise, you would be typing `cumsum(replace(df1$time_elapsed, is.na(df1$time_elapsed), 0..` etc